# Is there a tidier way to get call stack information than Environment.StackTrace?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to record the call stack on an object that gets passed around through some complicated multi-threaded code. `Environment.StackTrace` gives you that call stack but it's very difficult to read.

```
at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)\r\n   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()\r\n   at Foo.Bar.Biz(Monolith monolith) in C:\\Users\\Me\\Google\\Source\\Search.cs :line 70\r\n   at Blah.Nonsense.Business(Monolith monolith) in C:\\Users\\Me\\Google\\Source\\Prediction.cs :line 129\r\n   at ... you get the point
```

I just need to see the file, class, method, and line. Is there a correct way to get that information? Below is the method that I wrote but it's pretty ugly because of all the string manipulation.

```
public static List<string[]> GetCallstack()
{
    List<string[]> callstack = new List<string[]>();

    string stackTrace = Environment.StackTrace;
    string[] stackInstances = stackTrace.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (string stackInstance in stackInstances)
    {
        var stackInstanceComponents = stackInstance.Split(new string[] { ") in ", ":line " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (stackInstanceComponents.Length == 3)
        {
            string classAndMethod = string.Join(".", stackInstanceComponents[0].Split('.').Reverse().Take(2).Reverse().ToArray()) + ")";
            string path = string.Join("/", stackInstanceComponents[1].Split(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Reverse().Take(2).Reverse().ToArray()).Replace("at ", "");
            string line = stackInstanceComponents[2];

            if (classAndMethod != "Utility.GetCallstack()")
            {
                callstack.Add(new string[] { classAndMethod, path, line });
            }
        }
    }

    return callstack;
}
```

Comment: The MSDN's samples are rarely very helpful, but in this case [they sort of are](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace).

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-callstack/

```
using System.Diagnostics;

[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
  StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();           // get call stack
  StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();  // get method calls (frames)

  // write call stack method names
  foreach (StackFrame stackFrame in stackFrames)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(stackFrame.GetMethod().Name);   // write method name
  }
}
```

Use [`StackTrace.GetFrames()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframes) to get all frames and then each [`StackFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe) has [all required methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe#methods): [`GetFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getfilename), [`GetMethod()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getmethod), [`GetFileLineNumber()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getfilelinenumber) and for the classname you use `GetMethod().DeclaringType`...

Comment: FYI: OPs requirement is `I just need to see the file, class, method, and line.` your code only prints the method name, so no file or line.

Comment: @RandRandom Then look at [the documentation for StackFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe?view=netframework-4.8#methods).... It has it all... `GetFileName()`, `GetFileLineNumber()`, `GetMethod()`...

Comment: I mean, how do you think I got the code I'm using? Yeah, I googled it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` class instead. It will give you a hierarchical view of your stack trace. Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=netframework-4.8) for full details on the class and code examples that do what you want. Note however that you must also filter out what you need. However, `StackTrace` allows you to do it in a cleaner way. Another choice is to use the [StackFrame class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe?view=netframework-4.8) which provides more fine grained info. This class has the `GetFileName()`, `GetMethod()`, `GetFileLineNumber()` and for the class name you can use `GetMethod().DeclaringType`